# .NET 3.5 (or 2.0) in less than 100MB: it is possible?

Tags: .net, frameworks, size

I need to install and run an application written using .net 2.0, but I've less than 100 mb available.
The application is a simple service sizing about 1 mb.

Are there any chance to install the framework in a such little space available?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try? What problems do you encounter?

Comment: When we say yes, it may fail, when we say no it may work. So best thing is to try it out!

Comment: I've not tried yet because I'm on a industrial scenario, and I cannot "try" easily

Answer (score 0):

You can try the .NET 3.5 Client Profile.  It's a subset of the full framework but doesn't include the ASP.NET related items for IIS.  There might be some other differences, but I've never had any problems running Windows Apps or Services with the Client Profile.

This can be obtained from: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14037

Comment: Unfortunately in the link you wrote me there is this sentence:
"Hard Disk: Up to 500 MB of available space may be required"

Comment: Ahh sorry, I should have checked that.  That's really surprising that it would need that much.  I think the Client Profile is still your best bet...